# strapi error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, digital-ocean, strapi

On my Mac Book Pro where I develop
Strapi runs perfectly

When I upload the the code I have prepared to github
Then clone that code from github to my Digital Ocean Droplet that is running Ubuntu 20

When I try to run strapi with the code: `npm run develop` after making sure I run `npm install` on the project

I get the following errors:

```
> strapi@0.1.0 develop
> strapi develop

[2022-05-09 13:47:52.327] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2022-05-09 13:47:52.342] error: Could not load js config file /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/strapi-server.js: 
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'
Require stack:
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/services/image-manipulation.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/services/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/strapi-server.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/config-loader.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/develop.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js

Possible solutions:
- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp"
- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: "npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp"
- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
Error: Could not load js config file /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/strapi-server.js: 
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'
Require stack:
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/services/image-manipulation.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/services/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/server/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/plugin-upload/strapi-server.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/config-loader.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/index.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/commands/develop.js
- /home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js

Possible solutions:
- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp"
- Install for the current linux-x64 runtime: "npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp"
- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
    at loadJsFile (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js:18:11)
    at loadFile (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/app-configuration/load-config-file.js:35:14)
    at Object.loadPlugins (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/core/loaders/plugins/index.js:96:26)
    at async Strapi.loadPlugins (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:284:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Strapi.register (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:316:5)
    at async Strapi.load (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:414:5)
    at async Strapi.start (/home/bliss/strapi/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:163:9)
```

How do I get strapi to run on Digital Ocean???
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the `sharp` folder inside `node_modules` and ran `npm install` again

Comment: I removed the whole `node_modules` to do a fresh `npm install`. Thank you!

Comment: I am with @sergioruizsan. This is happening due to sharp having an OS specific version on install. Don't commit node_modules and let the install take care of anything OS specific (there are likely other conflicts you haven't seen yet).